# Sencha Touch select or highlight an item of nestedlist programally

Tags: list, select, nested, sencha-touch

I try to select/highlight an item of nestedlist with this code:

```
var activelist= nestedList.getActiveItem();
var listselectednode = activelist.getNode(1);
nestedPanel.fireEvent('itemtap',activelist,1,listselectednode ,e);
```

but not work.

Help

Comment: I found a solution:
var activelist= nestedList.getActiveItem();
var listselectednode = activelist.getNode(1);
nestedPanel.fireEvent('itemtap',activelist,1,listselectednode ,e); activelist.select(1, true);

Comment: If you found the answer, you should post an answer instead of a comment and then you can accept the answer once the allotted time has passed

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake here is how you just select (highlight) a node. This answer was adapted from the comments on the question.

```
var activeList = nestedList.getActiveItem();

// By index<br/>
activeList.getSelectionModel().select(index)

// By ID<br/>
var targetNode = activeList.store.getById(id);
activeList.getSelectionModel().select(targetNode);
```

And here is how you select and tap a node (by ID).

```
var activeList = nestedList.getActiveItem();
var targetNode = activeList.getNode(activeList.store.getById(targetNodeId));
var e = {} // You can provide event data here, if you like.

if (targetNode) {
  var targetIndex = activeList.indexOf(targetNode);

  nestedList.fireEvent('itemtap', activeList, targetIndex, targetNode , e);
  activeList.getSelectionModel().select(targetIndex, true);
}
```